Docker image build fails in terraform - failed to read downloaded context: failed to load cache key
I am having issue with building Docker image in terraform on MacOS 15.0.1, Terraform 1.7.3,  Docker Desktop 4.35.1, Docker Engine 24.0.2. The error I get:
Error: failed to read downloaded context: failed to load cache key: invalid response status 403


I ended up with a barebone setup where I could reproduce the error.
providers.tf:
terraform {
  required_providers {
    docker = {
      source  = "kreuzwerker/docker"
      version = "3.0.2"
    }
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "5.40.0"
    }
     google-beta = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google-beta"
      version = "5.19.0"
    }
  }
}

main.tf:
resource "docker_image" "my_image" {
  name         = "my_docker_image:latest"
  build {
    context    = "./app"
    dockerfile = "Dockerfile"
  }
}

Dockerfile:
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.10
# Use a base image
FROM nginx:latest
COPY index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html

index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Hello from Terraform-built Docker container!</h1>
</body>
</html>

It looks like terraform-provider-docker doesn't work with the new docker versions. I got it to work by downgrading to Docker Desktop 4.31.0, Docker Engine 26.1.4. It seems terraform-provider-docker is not maintained anymore. It is used in terraform oficial tutorials. Any ideas for a "better" fix?

This has been reported a couple of times last week. Can you check the Github repo for the provider if there are similar bug reports?

I can't see a bug report on it but there is 111 open issues. Even if there is a bug report on it it looks like there is nobody to fix it. The most recent version was released 2 years ago

You might try opening an issue for the tutorial instead, and Hashicorp may take responsibility for basic maintenance of the provider. They assumed responsibility for the Kubernetes provider years ago when it had similar issues.

@MatthewSchuchard - good idea. I will do it
